# Are linux interval timers prone to long-term average error?

Tags: time, timer, real-time, audio-streaming, rtp

My code below is designed to generate an AES67 compliant audio stream by transmitting an RTP packet containing audio samples once every millisecond. This is achieved with an interval timer referenced to CLOCK_REALTIME. In order to meet the requirements of AES67, CLOCK_REALTIME is synchronised to a PTP hardware clock by phc2sys, and the PTP hardware clock itself is managed by ptp4l. The code is running on a Beaglebone Black SBC (ARM Cortex-A8) which is also acting as PTP grand master with hardware timestamping enabled. I have the rt_preempt patch applied to the kernel and am running ptp4l, phc2sys and my code with real-time priorities 99, 98 and 97 respectively. (Scheduler mode is RR).

I've been testing the code with a hardware AES67 receiver which reports that PTP sync offset is well within 0.1μS. The system does work, however the receiver buffer in the receiver slowly empties and, after around 26 minutes, under-runs. I'm guessing that either:

a) there is a frequency error in one of the clock synchronisation mechanisms or

b) there is a long-term average error in the duration of the interval timer created by timerfd_create

I'm yet to find any evidence of a) so my question is, are there any known limitations or inadequacies in timerfd (or in my use of it) which could be causing this problem?

(Timer code is in the bottom third of the code sample.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include "random32.h"
#include "timestamp.h"

const int32_t int24_min = -8388608;
const int32_t int24_max = 8388607;

struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
struct timespec packetTime = {0, 1000000L};
struct itimerspec packetTimer;
uint16_t sequenceNumber = 0;
uint32_t timestamp = 0;
uint32_t ssrc = 0;
uint64_t expiration;
ssize_t s;
int type = 0;
int sd;
int td;
int sRate = 48000;
void tx(void);

//set the first two bytes of the RTP header
char txPacket[300] = {0b10000000, 0b01100100};
int packetLen = sizeof(txPacket);

//declare a pointer to the sequenceNumber in txPacket
char *sn = &txPacket[2];

//declare a pointer to the timestamp in txPacket
char *ts = &txPacket[4];

//declare a pointer to the synchronisation source identifier
char *ss = &txPacket[8];

//declare a pointer to the first audio sample in txPacket
char *as = &txPacket[12];

//declare a union of types int32_t and char[4] so that
//sample data can be accessed one byte at a time
union sample
{
  int32_t intSample;
  char bytes[4];
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
  //generate a unique ssrc and put it in the txPacket
  ssrc = htonl(random32(type));
  memcpy (ss, &ssrc, sizeof(ssrc));

  //generate 1kHz tone for the audio samples
  double angle = 0.0;
  double increment = 7.5 * (M_PI / 180);
  double amplitude;
  int i;

  union sample currentSample;
  currentSample.intSample = 0;

  for(i = 1; i < 49; i++)
  {
    //calculate amplitude based on sine of angular position
    //scale it to the maximum value of a 24-bit number
    amplitude = (sin(angle)) * int24_max;
    amplitude = round(amplitude);
    currentSample.intSample = (int32_t)amplitude;

    //copy the sample into the txpacket (twice for stereo),
    //reordiering bytes as big-endian
    memcpy (as, &currentSample.bytes[2], 1);
    as++;
    memcpy (as, &currentSample.bytes[1], 1);
    as++;
    memcpy (as, &currentSample.bytes[0], 1);
    as++;
    memcpy (as, &currentSample.bytes[2], 1);
    as++;
    memcpy (as, &currentSample.bytes[1], 1);
    as++;
    memcpy (as, &currentSample.bytes[0], 1);
    as++;

    angle = angle + increment;
  }

  //create the socket
  sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  //initialize the groupSock structure
  memset((char *)&groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
  groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
  groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.1.1.1");
  groupSock.sin_port = htons(5004);

  localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.4");
  setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface));

  //set the initial expiration and interval of the timer
  packetTimer.it_value = packetTime;
  packetTimer.it_interval = packetTime;

  //create and arm the timer
  td = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);
  timerfd_settime(td, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &packetTimer, NULL);

  s = read(td, &expiration, sizeof(uint64_t));  //wait for a timer expiration
  timestamp = getTimestamp();                   //get initial RTP timestamp value
  tx();                                         //send first packet

  for( ; ; )
  {
    s = read(td, &expiration, sizeof(uint64_t));  //wait for next timer expiration
    tx();                                         //send next packet
  }
  return 0;
}

void tx(void)
{
  //convert sequenceNumber to network byte order and copy it to the tx packet
  uint16_t beSequenceNumber = htons(sequenceNumber);
  memcpy (sn, &beSequenceNumber, sizeof(beSequenceNumber));

  //convert timestamp to network byte order and copy it to the tx packet
  uint32_t beTimestamp = htonl(timestamp);
  memcpy (ts, &beTimestamp, sizeof(beTimestamp));

  //send packet
  sendto(sd, txPacket, packetLen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock));

  //increment sequence number
  sequenceNumber++;

  //increment timestamp
  timestamp = timestamp + 48;
}
```

Comment: I can't answer your question... but I'm really excited for anyone getting AES67 working well on these boards, so +1!  So many possible use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging real-time problems is always a bit hairy.  The first thing that would help is to be able to find out what your program is actually doing by monitoring it from outside.
Do you have:  a scope, logic analyzer, or anything equivalent?

If so, change your program to toggle a gpio before reading the timer, and after reading the timer.  Attach your analyzer to this gpio line, and carefully measure the duty cycle of the resultant waveform.

If not, scrape together a second computer with either a real serial port or some sort of signal recognizer.   Set the baud rate on the beagle to something pretty high: 1 MB should suffice.  Insert code to write to the serial port before and after reading the time.   On the second computer, which you have attached this to, disable interrupts, and record the timestamp each time a character is read.  Plot this time series, and carefully measure the waveform.

These steps will tell you how well you are doing at producing your data in a timely fashion.

I suspect that your timer is not functioning the way that you think it is.  I suspect that it is always returning from read immediately, and that buffering and protocol are making it appear to work for 26 minutes (1.5M packets) until the wheels fall of.   But that is just mumbling supposition.  Measurements tell the real story.

On the other hand, if your timer is functioning correctly, you should see it slowly drift off over the 26 minutes, indicating either that pptp isn't quite right, or that you should be using the monotonic timer.

Comment: thanks, I can access a 'scope at work so I'll try this test.

I think the system is working for ~26 mins as the receiver can capture the stream to file and this reveals an intact sine wave as expected.

The receiver also offers a graph of buffer fill against time. This shows that the fill level decreases from an initial healthy state to zero over time. Interestingly though, this is not a straight line tending towards zero, rather it is a stepped plot where the buffer is stable, then suddenly drops by 48 samples, then repeats.. (48 is the number of audio samples in one RTP packet.)

Comment: I've added some logging to record the number of timer expirations which have occurred in between each timer read. Of course this should always be 1, however it transpires that it's occasionally more than that. Increasing the timer interval to 2ms eliminates this error. (Unfortunately 2ms is not a supported "packet time" in AES67.) I'll try running my code on a more powerful* system to see if this has a positive impact. *More powerful being higher clock speed, and also multi-core so I can dedicate a CPU core to my packet transmission routine.

Comment: I have spent a lot of my career in real time operating systems.  Early on, I was frequently exposed to "real time is fast enough"; yet despite seeing average instruction rates go from about 1M/s to 1000M/s; "fast enough has never hit real time".  Real time is an implementation choice to optimize for the worst case, and fight for bounded responsiveness.   Even really fast cpus end up with pathalogical cases.  That is OK if you are serving web sites; less so for cooling rods.

Comment: Get Linux, apply the real time patch.  Measure, measure, measure.  Pick on Steve Rostedt about why the Q isn't what you want (tell him I sent you).  if you get really frustrated, tally up the cost of a commercial offering -- QNX, VxWorks, Nucleus, ....

Comment: Thanks again mevets. I'm now running with the real time kernel patch on a multi-core machine. I've got the PTP daemon and my audio tx code running on separate cores and have achieved stable audio streaming (into a hardware receiver) for over 16 hours without interruption. I guess the Beaglebone platform is a bit resource-limited for this work, and may need further optimisation if it's to be useable. The good news is that timerfd does seem to be accurate enough, just need to make sure there are enough clock cycles in between expirations to get other work done.